# PixiJS: Draw line with mousemove

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Pixijs
I'm trying to draw a single line using OnMouseMove(), my problem is that everytime I move the mouse It leaves a trail

my progress [codepen](https://codepen.io/anibalajt/pen/KKyPMmX)

```js
var sprite = new PIXI.Graphics();
let initPointer = null;

const onMouseMove = (e) => {
  if (initPointer == null) return;
  sprite.lineStyle(2, 0xff0000, 1);
  sprite.moveTo(initPointer.x, initPointer.y);

  const mousePosRef = getMousePos(e);
  sprite.lineTo(mousePosRef.x, mousePosRef.y);
  console.log(sprite);

  annoRef.addChild(sprite);
  sprite = new PIXI.Graphics();
};
const onMouseDown = (e) => {
  const mousePosRef = getMousePos(e);
  initPointer = mousePosRef;
  // sprite.moveTo(initPointer.x, initPointer.y);
};
```

[image]

what I need, any help

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Changed your code a little bit: https://codepen.io/domis86/pen/LYOYrVx

main points:

- see `isMouseButtonDown` variable usage
- `sprite.clear();` executed in `onMouseMove` - so on each move the Graphics object properties are resetted and one line is drawn. Previously on each move new line was "added" to Graphics object using `sprite.moveTo` and `sprite.lineTo`.
- `sprite = new PIXI.Graphics();` is executed in `onMouseDown` instead of `onMouseUp`. This way we create new Graphics object (a "line") when mouse is clicked - is more natural behaviour IMO.
- Please rename your variable `sprite` because it suggests this is a Sprite ( https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html ) but in reality it Graphics :) So `line` or `graphics` would be more suitable names IMHO ;)